# Why PINxn with pullup reads zero when nothing is connected to it?

Tags: atmega, atmega32u4

Consider the following C-program:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
int main(void)
{
  DDRB |= 1 << PB0; /* LED */
  PORTB |= 1 << PB5; /* pullup */
  if (!(PINB & 1 << PB5)) 
    PORTB |= 1 << PB0; /* turn on LED */
  while (1) ;
}
```

There are two situations:

- connect a 10cm wire to `PB5` pin (the other end of the wire is in the air): the result is that sometimes after poweron the led is on, sometimes the led is not on.
- do not connect anything to `PB5` pin: the result is that after poweron led is never on.

In [datasheet](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/atmega32u4.pdf) in section 10.2.4 "Reading the Pin Value" nothing applies to this case.

The question is: what causes `PINB & 1 << PB5` to read zero value, in spite of the fact that it is pulled up; and how to solve this issue?

---

If I add a 10ms delay after pulling up, led is never on after poweron. Why? Where is it described?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <util/delay.h>
int main(void)
{
  DDRB |= 1 << PB0; /* LED */
  PORTB |= 1 << PB5; /* pullup */
  _delay_ms(10);
  if (!(PINB & 1 << PB5))
    PORTB |= 1 << PB0; /* turn on LED */
  while (1) ;
}
```

But this delay is just to show that there is something wrong - I do not want to use the delay to solve this issue - I want to know the *cause* (and *the proper* fix).

(*Note: in my project this wire hanging in the air is one end of a button switch, and micro controller sometimes detects that a button was pressed (while it was not), which is a big problem.*)

---

**EDIT**

The "synchronizer" does not help. In the following example some instructions are executed after enabling pullup. But the behavior is the same as originally described.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
int main(void)
{
  PORTB |= 1 << PB5; /* pullup */
  DDRB |= 1 << PB0; /* LED */
  if (!(PINB & 1 << PB5))
    PORTB |= 1 << PB0; /* turn on LED */
  while (1) ;
}
```

**EDIT2** See also [this](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/54923/14631) answer.

Comment: Is `avr/io.h` and `util/delay.h` official libraries from Atmel or they from some author from GitHub? If it is from GitHub, could you include the links to the libraries?

Comment: @KingDuken I use AVR-GCC 5.4.0 (from Debian repository)

Comment: This condition "if ( !(PINB & (1 << PB5)) )" will only give you a TRUE if pin is at LOW state.

Comment: @G36 That's exactly what is happening. And this is the problem.

Comment: Why are you connecting a 10 cm open ended wire to your port? It will act like a 750 MHz quarter wave monopole antenna? Is that what you want?

Comment: @Andyaka See *Note* at the end of OP.

Comment: It will still act like an antenna and should be bypassed to ground/0 volts with maybe 100 pF to prevent problems arising.

Comment: @Andyaka I enable the **pullup** to prevent problems arising. But it does not work (without a delay). I want to know the cause of this.

Comment: What resistive value is the pull-up? Anything greater than 1 kohm could be argued to be too large.

Comment: I am afraid delay is the proper cure. You activate the pullup and immediately (a few hundred nanoseconds later) read the port pin. Pullup hasn't yet charged input capacitance and  so you read a random value. Probably 10ms is much more than what needed, but some delay is indeed  called for.

Comment: @Andyaka It is the built-in pullup. It should be enough.

Comment: @carloc How do I calculate precisely the minimal delay interval? Where is the formula? Where is it described?

Comment: Just consider worst case,: charging maximum input capacitance via the higher possible tolerance internal pullup from minimum input voltage (possibly one diodes drop below GND) to higher input threshold. Some datasheet reading and educated guess is what it takes to fill in the above values. Rough estimate a few hundred picofarads times s few tens kilo ohms times five... Say approx 10 to 50 microseconds, it could just be the time taken for do some other initialisations in your program

Comment: @carloc all this seems rather flaky...

Comment: The internal pull-up resistor value is around 30kOhms. Try to add a stronger external pull-up (1k) and disable internal pull-up.

Comment: @G36 I would prefer to use built-in pullup ...

Comment: But you could try it to test whether the theory is right.

Comment: @G36 Even if this will solve the problem, this will not say anything about the real cause of the problem. So, there is no sense to test it. I want to know the real cause of the problem. Guesses is not what I'm looking for. Do you know any formulas or scientific explanations of what is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to page 68 of your datasheet.
Have a look at the 2nd paragraph

> When reading back a software assigned pin value, a nop instruction
>   must be inserted as indicated ...

The same rational applies here when you enable the pullup - you need at least a single-instruction delay between enabling the pullup (or setting the output) and reading the pin state.
This allows the IO synchronization flip-flops (See the "SYNCHRONIZER" block in Fig 10-2 on page 66) to do their job.

Since you've indicated that you have some 'long' wires connected to this pin, you might have enough capacitance on the line to further delay the rise-time of the signal, so it's possible that a single `nop` might not be enough.
But you would need to do some careful measurements (looking at the rise-time) or calculations (the RC time constant using the values of pullup resistance and extra capacitance) to be sure.

Comment: First of all, the situation described in datasheet does not apply to my case: I do not want read back value assigned by software - I want to read an external value. Secondly, I tested your suggestion and it does not work (see **EDIT** in OP). The mystery is still not solved...

Comment: The situation described in the datasheet does apply to your case. The Synchonizer doesn't behave differently to externally applied signal levels vs the pullup. Your re-ordering attempt simply shows that there needs to be more of a delay, probably because of the additional capacitance and rise-time you haven't account for.

Comment: And to be clear - the syncronizer only accounts for the single-cycle delay. Any additional delay required is due to the slow rise-time of the input level cause by the large pullup resistance and external capacitance.

Comment: OK, maybe you are right... I just can't wrap my head around that diagrams in datasheet... Will try to find a more understandable explanation of this "synchonizer" stuff somewhere...

Comment: As G36 indicated in a comment on your question, a stronger external pullup could help a lot. But the required delay will never be less than one nop (due to the synchronizer).